# Dealing with Rsync scenarios

Tags: php, rsync

**Hello everyone,**

I'm currently trying to write some kind of archive manager in PHP, with a daily function which will be called by a cron.

The goal is to use rsync between "old code" and "current dev directory" and IF there's any changes, rebuild my zip files accordingly to a specific structure (eg. Folder_A changed, so I will only rebuild the *Archive_A.zip* which will be composed of the content of *Folder_A* and *Folder_Generic*).

The problem is that I don't really know WHEN there's actual change in my code with my rsync :

`exec('rsync -avzh --delete '.$src_path.' '.$oldsrc_path.' ', $tab)`

And $tab is usually an array with the output of rsync (each key = 1 line) :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "sending incremental file list"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(51) "sent 100 bytes  received 12 bytes  224.00 bytes/sec"
  [3]=>
  string(32) "total size is 0  speedup is 0.00"
}
```

or when I force some change (deleted one file from the "old code" directory) :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "sending incremental file list"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "./"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "file_a2.txt"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(51) "sent 143 bytes  received 38 bytes  362.00 bytes/sec"
  [5]=>
  string(32) "total size is 0  speedup is 0.00"
}
```

Currently I'm using $tab[1] which seems to be an empty string when there's no change, but I wonder if that will always be the case, or if there is a better way to do this.

What do you think ?

**Thanks in advance for you insight**

*~*~ **Linximon**